# What is wrong with this?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT KundeID, Kundenummer, Fornavn, Efternavn, Adresse, Postnummer, [By] 
FROM dbo.Kundeliste
INNER JOIN Ordreliste
ON Ordreliste.KundeID<>Kundeliste.KundeID
```

I dont get the right output. I need all customers that not yet has placed an order from my customerlist

Comment: try sth like: `SELECT ... from dbo.Kundeliste where not KundeID in (select KundeID from Ordreliste)`

Comment: Well, the INNER JOIN only returns those that **have** already placed an order - that's the main problem in your query. See Martin's excellent answer - that's the way to go

Answer (score 6):

You need an [anti semi join](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/07/19/671712.aspx). The three most common ways of doing this are `NOT EXISTS`, `NOT IN`, and `OUTER JOIN` filtering on `NULL`.

I generally use `NOT EXISTS` as it avoids issues with `NULL`s that the `NOT IN` has and generally gets [the most efficient plan](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/).

```
SELECT KundeID,
       Kundenummer,
       Fornavn,
       Efternavn,
       Adresse,
       Postnummer,
       [By]
FROM   dbo.Kundeliste
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   Ordreliste
                   WHERE  Ordreliste.KundeID = Kundeliste.KundeID)
```

Your current query with the `<>` condition does nearly an entire cartesian/cross join. For each row in `dbo.Kundeliste` it will join on all of the rows in `Ordreliste` **except** those with the same `KundeID` or where the `KundeID` is null.

Comment: Also: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4010/630